# Deployement of ASP.NET application getting error

Tags: asp.net

I have deployed my asp.net application (VS 2005) through iis 7.5,
while browsing page(e.g localhost/MyApp/login.aspx) from iis it shows

```
Cannot find table 0.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Cannot find table 0.
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're accessing an array with the wrong index. That's what the exception says. For example, trying to access element 10 in an array of 9 elements produces this exception.

Comment: Without seeing the code that's throwing the error, we can't really advise on a way to fix it.  Whatever `table` is, it sounds like there aren't any of them.  And you're trying to access one.  Hence the error.

Comment: The exception itself is brief saying table now found

Comment: You maybe have a dataset and try to access first table by ds.Tables[0].

Answer (score 0):

Your "table" array/collection has zero elements.

Comment: @PranavG : surround the code with condition...`if(DataSet.Tables.Count > 0){}`

Answer (score 0):

problem is solved...

i set Anonymus Authentication in IIS Authentication enabled while all other disabled...

in Advace setting of application pool created by me :

```
                   - Managed PipeLine : Local System

                   - Load User Profile : True
```

in Default website -> Basic setting -> connect as -> select Application User(pass-through authentication)

thx for the help...